# Raspberry 4B stuck in splash screen at boot, randomly. Kiosk mode

Tags: raspbian, boot, kiosk

So, here is my problem. 
I'm using new Raspberry 4B, with 4gb for kiosk mode, with Raspbian Lite. I was having problems previously, because of two hdmi's, but i fixed this. 
Only Chrome is running and some custom apps, and there is reboot with crontab every morning (at 1.30 a.m.). 
Power supply is original at it should be, also sd cards are the same. We use micro-hdmi to hdmi cable, so without any cheap adapters. At room we have 8 systems, but at reboot some stays on splash screen. 
I'm running this same system on raspberry 3B+, and i didn't have this issue.

Also worth to mention, i add boot_delay=1 at config file. But this only helps me a little bit.

Thanks, for any suggestions.

Best regards, Blaz

Comment: Collect the logs from a system that fails to boot.

Comment: log file from /var/syslog:

https://pastebin.com/raw/y5u27gYg